# Powerpoint looping of slides

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I am wanting to create a powerpoint where the first 10 slides are automatically looped with audio, and set on a timer between the 10 slides. This is easy to do, however I need a way to escape the loop and continue on with the slideshow whenever I click (click and move to slide 11).

Is this possible?

Comment: Could you explain how you did the looping so that this is more useful to people (and also to help get your question answered)?

Comment: I created an automatic advance of slide after a specific time. So the slideshow would simple change from slide 1 -> 2 -> 3 etc. once it reaches slide 11 it would stop.

Comment: What have you researched or attempted so far?

Comment: What version are you using and I can give you specific instructions.

Answer (score 1):

The only and most easy-to-use option that I know of is creating a (transparent) object on slides 1-10. To that object, you can attach a hyperlink to slide 11, which will escape the loop.

The downside of this is that you have to click on that object specifically, but you can make it as big as the whole slide if you want to.